# I have string with Start date and Target Date and I want to take date and save in variable in Java

Tags: java, parsing

This is my string Start Date: May 22, 2015  End Date: June 17, 2015
I want to take first May 22, 2015 and after that June 17, 2015

Comment: Is `Start Date: May 22, 2015 End Date: June 17, 2015` a single String?

Answer (score 1):

1) Replace the words (Start Date and End Date) with empty strings

2) Split by :

3) Trim and store

```
 String date= "Start Date: May 22, 2015 End Date: June 17, 2015";
 date = date.replace("Start Date","");
 date = date.replace("End Date","");
 String dates[] = date.split(":");
 String startDate  =  dates[1].trim();
 String endDate=  dates[2].trim();
```

I hope, this will get compiled successfully.

Answer (score 0):

```
public static void main(String ards[]) throws ParseException {

    SimpleDateFormat formtter = new SimpleDateFormat("MMM dd, yyyy");
    String dateStr = "Start Date: May 22, 2015 End Date: June 17, 2015 ";
    String arr[] = dateStr.split(": ");

    String date1 = arr[1].split(" End Date")[0];
    Date d1 = formtter.parse(date1);
    System.out.println(date1);

    String date2 = arr[2].trim();
    Date d2 = formtter.parse(date2);
    System.out.println(date2);
}
```

Comment: would not give correct output because you are splitting by ': ' and there won't be any space before ' END Date'

Comment: @Danyal runs fine,  run the code